# Spring 3 + Quartz 2 error

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I received the error below when I use Spring 3 with Quartz 2.  Does anyone knows the reason?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean] for bean with name 'job' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean has interface org.quartz.JobDetail as super class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1253)
```

Spring config file:

```
<bean name="job" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
  <property name="jobClass" value="Example.ExampleJob"/>
  <property name="jobDataAsMap">
    <map>
      <entry key="timeout" value="5"/>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="job"/>
  <property name="startDelay" value="1000"/>
  <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000"/>
</bean>

public class ExampleJob extends QuartzJobBean {

      private int timeout;

      /**
       * Setter called after the ExampleJob is instantiated
       * with the value from the JobDetailBean (5)
       */ 
      public void setTimeout(int timeout) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
      }

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        *****
    }

}
```

Comment: Please make topics meaningful

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Last I checked, Spring doesn't have support for Quartz 2.  Either have a look to see if the most recent Spring builds have added said support, or try downgrading to Quartz 1.8.x.

Comment: Your are right. Quartz 2 support is added in 3.1. Check http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/changelog.txt

Comment: Why must you torment me so Spring? I swear I would be about as productive making my own implementation than using Spring's and running into delightful undocumented issues like these.

Comment: I am using Spring 3.2.4, the Javadoc in class "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" says "Compatible with Quartz 1.5+ as well as Quartz 2.0-2.2, as of Spring 3.2". But I am STILL getting this error. Has anyone been able to make Spring 3.2.x run with Quartz 2.2.x?

Comment: @Adi Does it mean that I can not user quartz 2.3.0 with Spring 2.5 web application?

Answer (score 46):

If you use Spring 3.1,

Replace the SimpleTriggerBean with SimpleTriggerFactoryBean

In the 3.1 release, Spring has created Factory classes for crontrigger and simpletrigger

Update:

> Using Spring 3.2.2, must be useful to change also JobDetailBean =>
>   JobDetailFactoryBean and CronTriggerBean => CronTriggerFactoryBean.

Credit to Osy (vote on the comment below)

Comment: Using Spring 3.2.2, must be useful to change also JobDetailBean => JobDetailFactoryBean and CronTriggerBean => CronTriggerFactoryBean.

Comment: A vote for Osy (I've voted for his comment, but I've undone the vote by mistake, and now I can't "upvote" again) Side note: In JobDetailFactoryBean set durability to true if you see "Jobs added with no trigger must be durable" error

Answer (score 19):

According to the [3.1.0.RC1 Change Log](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/changelog.txt), Spring 3.1 has support for Quartz 2.x.

For every `{Type}TriggerBean` there is now a `{Type}TriggerBeanFactory` which can be used to setup triggers. In your case this would be [`SimpleTriggerFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SimpleTriggerFactoryBean.html)

**Excerpt**

> **NOTE:** This FactoryBean works against both Quartz 1.x and Quartz 2.0/2.1, in contrast to the older SimpleTriggerBean class.

**Sidenote**

You might also need to add the org.springframework.transaction dependency, depending on which type of trigger you are using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

We needed it for migration to Quartz 2 in a configuration using [`CronTriggerFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/CronTriggerFactoryBean.html) triggers.

Answer (score 17):

If You are using Spring 3.x & Quartz 2.1.x…

Then do only two changes IN YOUR configuration file
1st : for Simple Trigger

Use `class=”org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean”>` instead of
`class=”org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean”>`

2nd : for Cron Trigger
use `class=”org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean”` instead of
`class=”org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean”`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was result from duplicate quartz lib. I have include a exclusion in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>openejb-core-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.openejb.shade</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz-openejb-shade</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```