# Is it possible to implement an event driven SFTP inbound adapter instead of a poller driven adapter using Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a requirement to develop an SFTP adapter which will download files from a remote location. This process will be scheduled using a quartz scheduler and the schedule time will be set from a gui. I was initially using spring SFTP inbound adapter but I realized that it is a poller consumer. However I want it to be invoked by my quartz scheduler instead of the poller. Could it be done? Can I make my SFTP inbound adapter event driven instead of poller driven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you have a few options...

1. Use `outbound-gateway`(s) instead; you can use one gateway to list (`ls`) the remote directory, followed by a `<splitter/>` and another outbound gateway to `get` the files; a third gateway can then `rm` the remote file(s). There's an example of that in the [SFTP Sample App](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp) Or, you can use a single `<outbound-gateway/>` to `mget` all the files matching a pattern (e.g. `/foo/*.txt`).
2. Use the technique I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563469/spring-integration-cron-quartz-in-cluster/11564543#11564543).