# Move files from one directory to another when request coming from another system

Tags: spring-integration

I want to use read files in one directory and move to another directory, I am using spring-integration  for this. I want to execute the task(move files to output directory) when request coming from another system. I do not want to run file mover repeatedly, Is there a way to do this in Spring Integration?

Thank you in advance,
Udeshika

Comment: Yes, but the actual configuration will depend on how the other system triggers the action. You need to explain your use case in more detail to get a detailed answer.

Comment: In spring-integration, we must use the <int:pollar>(time interval to run the job) within the <file:inbound-channel-adapter>,In my case I do not need that functionality, I want, when external system calls the spring-integration module, run the task and stop,can I do that using <file:inbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: Right, but you are not explaining how the "external system `calls` the SI module". If you can explain the trigger, I can give you a solution.

Comment: using operating system scheduler(cron job),we call the main method using cron, after processing all the files we want shout down file processing module,if we use <file:inbound-channel-adapter> we can't do that(as I understood),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some tricks you can do with pollers, such as the FireOnceTrigger I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563469/spring-integration-cron-quartz-in-cluster/11564543#11564543). But in this case, probably the simplest solution is, instead of using an inbound adapter, define a `<bean/>` of type `FileReadingMessageSource` in your context; get a reference to it in your main() (`context.getBean(FileReadingMessagesource.class)`). Keep calling `receive()` and send the message received to the first channel in your flow (or use a `<gateway/>`.

When `receive()` returns null, exit.

Comment: Thank you,I'm bit new to the spring-integration,Is there any example which i can refer?,Can I process and move files using "FileReadingMessageSource"?

Comment: We don't have an explicit example for your use case; just declare the `FileReadingMessageSource` as you would any other bean; get a reference to it, or inject it, and call `receive()` and you'll get a `Message<File>` object that you can then send to your SI flow to process and move it.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm working on this, let you know the progress

Answer (score 0):

Example for read specified file from samba share without poller:

FileService.java bean:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.smb.session.SmbSession;
import org.springframework.integration.smb.session.SmbSessionFactory;
 ...
@Component
public class FileService {
    private @Autowired ApplicationContext appContext;
    ... 
    private byte[] getFileContent( final String filename ) {
        final SmbSessionFactory smbSessionFactory = (SmbSessionFactory) appContext.getBean("MySmbSession");
        final SmbSession smbSession = smbSessionFactory.getSession();
        final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            smbSession.read("mysharefolder\" + filename, output);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        return output.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

spring_integration.xml config file:

```
...
<!-- smb configuration for samba  smb://[[[domain;]username[:password]@]server[:port]/[[share/[dir/]file]]][?[param=value[param2=value2[...]]] -->
<bean id="MySmbSession" class="org.springframework.integration.smb.session.SmbSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${samba.host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${samba.port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${samba.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${samba.password}"/>
    <property name="shareAndDir" value="${samba.shareAndDir}"/>
    <property name="replaceFile" value="true"/>
</bean>
...
```

application.yml config file:

```
samba:
  host : '${SAMBA_HOST:172.16.0.7}'
  hostAlias : '${SAMBA_HOST_ALIAS:mywinsrv}'
  port : '${SAMBA_PORT:445}'
  username : '${SAMBA_USER_NAME:DMZ\myusername}' 
  password : '${SAMBA_USER_PASS:mypassword}'
  shareAndDir : '${SAMBA_SHARE_AND_DIR:myDocs$\myproject\}'
```