# Stopping a file inbound channel adapter after one one file is read

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

Our application uses a Spring Integration `file:inbound-channel-adapter` to poll a directory to listen to when a file is dropped there. Spring Integration then starts a Spring Batch job, handing over to the job the path and name of the file to process.

Obviously, the file poller continues to run even after a file has been processed by the Spring Batch job. So, the Spring context remains open and the application does not terminate. Is there a way, programatically or through configuration (preferable), to stop the poller after one file has been read?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `FireOnceTrigger` on the poller, or one of the techniques described in addition to that, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063311/move-files-from-one-directory-to-another-when-request-coming-from-another-system/17081092#17081092).

To programmatically stop the adapter, `close()` the context, or call `adapter.stop()` (`@Autowire` the adapter as a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. Or use a `<control-bus/>` and send a message with payload `"adapterId.stop()"`.