# Spring Integration poller starting same Spring Batch job multiple times

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

Our application uses Spring Integration to kick off a Spring Batch job.

It works as follows:

1) The main application class is run, and this loads the Spring application context.

2) A Spring Integration bean is configured to read a file from the file system, and to place the file on a channel.

```xml
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
   directory="${...}" channel="channel"
   filename-pattern="*.csv" auto-create-directory="false" prevent-duplicates="true">
   <int:poller fixed-delay="${...}"></int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

3) The channel connects to a `@ServiceActivator` bean.

```xml
<int:service-activator input-channel="channel" ref="launcher" />
```

4) The Launcher bean gets the file from the message payload, and launches the Spring Batch job.

The problem is that after the `poller fixed-delay` time has elapsed, the launcher bean will be called again, and a new Job will be started with the same parameters.
This throws a `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException`.

I do not see anyway to tell the poller to only run once.
What is the recommended way to use Spring Integration and Spring Batch together to avoid this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Share, please, `DEBUG` logs for the `org.springframework.integration` category to see what's going on with your messages.

Comment: Use a fire once trigger. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229145/stopping-a-file-inbound-channel-adapter-after-one-one-file-is-read/25231018#25231018).