# sftp spring integration - pulling files from remote

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, sftp

I want to pull the files from remote server to my local. I am using Spring Integration SFTP to pull the files. I have the following configuration:

```
<sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpAdapterAutoCreate"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" channel="inputChannel"
        filename-pattern="*.txt" remote-directory="/remotedir"
        local-directory="file:target/foo" auto-create-local-directory="true"

        delete-remote-files="false"  >
          <int:poller fixed-rate="30000" /> 

</sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I dont want to delete the files from remotedir after the successful pull. Here what is happening is for every 30 seconds, the file(s) from the remotedir is getting pulled to my local. I want the spring batch program to stop after the first time and not pull the same file again. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The inbound channel adapter uses a notion of directory synchronization; if your flow removes the file, it will be re-fetched to synchronize the local directory. It won't be emitted as a message, though, because the local-filter is an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. However, that does not survive a system restart.

You could use a `CompositeFileListFilter` to include an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` along with the `SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter`. This will prevent re-fetching and will survive a system restart; it needs a `MetadataStore` to store the state, however.

To run only once, you can use a [FireOnceTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229145/stopping-a-file-inbound-channel-adapter-after-one-one-file-is-read/25231018#25231018) and set the `max-messages-per-poll` to `-1` so all files are fetched on the single poll.

You could also consider using an outbound gateway to `get` only those files that you want.