# Is there a way to start the file:inbound-channel-adapter through code?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a situation where a particular file is to be copied from a location to another. The polling is not required as the action will be deliberately triggered. Also the directory from which the file is to be picked up is decided at run time.

I can have a configuration as follows:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="@outPathBean.getPath()" channel="abc" filter="compositeFilter" >
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000" />

</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:channel id="abc"/>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="abc" id="filesOut"
    directory-expression="file:${paths.root}"
    delete-source-files="true" filename-generator="fileNameGenerator" />
```

filenamegenerator and composite filter classes are configured as well.

I am new to spring. Please point me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `FireOnceTrigger` as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563469/spring-integration-cron-quartz-in-cluster/11564543#11564543) and start/stop the adapter as needed.

To get a reference to the adapter (a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`), inject (or `@Autowire` etc.) it as a `Lifecycle` bean (`start()`/`stop()` etc).

Or you can do the whole thing programmatically using a `FileReadingMessageSource`, and discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063311/move-files-from-one-directory-to-another-when-request-coming-from-another-system/17081092#17081092).

Comment: will try this referred answer

Comment: any more details?? I am new to spring integration

Comment: Exactly what are you struggling with? Those answers go into some detail.

Comment: Here is what I understand from the first option: 1.  Change the poller tag in my xml  to :<int:poller trigger="my-trigger"/>. 2. Add a bean <bean id="my-trigger"
   class="Myclass">
  </bean> 3. public static class FireOnceTrigger implements Trigger {

    boolean done;

    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        if (done) {
            return null;
        }
        done = true;
        return new Date();
    }

    public void reset() {
        done = false;
    }
} 4. I can use @Autowire but dont know how to use it as a Lifecycle bean.

Comment: ?? Just `@Autowire` a `SourcePollingChannnelAdapter` or `Lifecycle` with the adapter's id and call `start()` on it.

Comment: will try and post results

Answer (score 0):

Sample for start/stop Adapter.incase its useful.

```
SourcePollingChannelAdapter sourcePollingChannelAdapter = (SourcePollingChannelAdapter) context
                .getBean("filesIn");  //adapter id in the bean configuration
        // Stop
        if (sourcePollingChannelAdapter.isRunning()) {
            sourcePollingChannelAdapter.stop();
        }
        // Set Cron Expression if required when start or use any triggers
        CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("* * * * * ?");
        sourcePollingChannelAdapter.setTrigger(cronTrigger);

        // Start
        if (!sourcePollingChannelAdapter.isRunning()) {
            sourcePollingChannelAdapter.start();
        }
```