# One time flow, batch processing

Tags: spring-integration

I need to write an one time flow in SI. I can develop it like any
 other SI flow. I beleive i do not need a polar in this case. My
 inbound adapter starts a SI flow, i can make it auto start or start
 manually from start up class.  When the flow is completed the process
 shuts down and return code is sent back to the caller (a scheduling
 tool). Is there anything built in in SI for such cases? If not, what are the key concepts to build this flow in spring integration.

Thanks

Comment: Let us know if [Spring Integration Flow](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow) fits your requirements.

Comment: You can also use a poller with a `FireOnceTrigger` as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708039/is-there-a-way-to-start-the-fileinbound-channel-adapter-through-code/26715238#26715238) (follow links).