# How to manually trigger an ftp inbound-channel-adapter poll?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

How do I trigger an FTP poll manually when I have an ftp inbound-channel-adapter defined like this?

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="id" 
    channel="ftpIn" 
    session-factory="sessionFactory" 
    filename-regex="${pattern}" 
    auto-create-local-directory="true" 
    delete-remote-files="false" 
    remote-directory="${remotedir}" 
    local-directory="${localdir}" 
    auto-startup="false">

        <int:poller id="poller" cron="0 15 19 * * MON-FRI" max-messages-per-poll="4" />

    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to make it fire in advance of of it's schedule, there is no way to do that; you can write a custom trigger, allowing the schedule to be changed, but the change won't take effect until after the next scheduled poll. This is explored in the [Dynamic Poller Sample App](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/dynamic-poller).

Another technique is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563469/spring-integration-cron-quartz-in-cluster/11564543#11564543) where the adapter has a trigger that fires once and polling is controlled by stopping/starting the adapter.

Finally, for 'on-demand' ftp actions, consider using the [Outbound Gateway](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway) instead. The [FTP Sample App](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp) has an example.