# Spring-Integration-SFTP download and process files

Tags: spring-integration

I have used the below suggestion and able to download the files from the remote server. If I want to process the files after the download completes then how do I proceed? Can someone please guide me on how/where to get the control once the files are downloaded to my local system

[spring integration + cron + quartz in cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563469/spring-integration-cron-quartz-in-cluster/11564543#11564543)

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">    

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.reports"/>    

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:reports.properties"/> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory"
        id="sftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}"/>
        <property name="privateKey" value="${sftp.key.location}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${sftp.user}"/>
    </bean> 

    <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter 
        id="sftpInboundAdapter"
        auto-startup="false"
        auto-create-local-directory="false"
        channel="receiveChannel"
        delete-remote-files="false"
        filter = "customfilter"
        remote-file-separator="/"
        local-directory="${local.directory}"
        remote-directory="${remote.directory}"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        preserve-timestamp="true"
        local-filter="acceptAll">

        <int:poller trigger="sftp-trigger"/>
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="receiveChannel">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

    <bean id="customfilter" class="com.reports.filters.ReportsFileListFilter"/> 
    <bean id="acceptAll" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter" />        
    <bean id="sftp-trigger" class="com.reports.jobs.ReportsTrigger"/>

    <!-- Quartz job --> 
    <!--  (1) Trigger - This is used in the Scheduler below --> 
    <bean id="ReportCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="ReportsJob"/>
        <property name="cronExpression" value="${cron.expression}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- (2) Job -->
    <bean name="ReportsJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.reports.jobs.ReportsJob"/>
        <property name="name" value="ReportsJob" />
        <property name="durability" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- (3) Scheduler -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
            <map>               
                <entry key="inputEndpoint"><ref bean="sftpInboundAdapter" /></entry>
                <entry key="inputEndpointTrigger"><ref bean="sftp-trigger" /></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />      
        <property name="quartzProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">ReportsBatchScheduler</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">dbo.QRTZ_</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">1</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL">SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="ReportCronTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"><value>java:/MSSQLDS_APP</value></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Custom Filter**

```
public class ReportsFileListFilter extends AbstractFileListFilter<LsEntry> {    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    @Override
    protected boolean accept(LsEntry file) {
        if (".".equals(file.getFilename()) || "..".equals(file.getFilename())) {
            return false;
        }
        String dt = sdf.format(new Date());         
        if (file != null && file.getFilename().contains(dt)) {
            Log.logDebug(ReportsFileListFilter.class, "Downloading File :: "+file.getFilename());               
            return true;
        }
        return false;       
    }
}
```

**Trigger**

```
public class ReportsTrigger implements Trigger {
    boolean done;

    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {        
        if (done) {
            return null;
        }
        done = true;
        Log.logDebug(ReportsTrigger.class, "Job started for date :: "+new Date());        
        return new Date();        
    }

    public void reset() {
        Log.logDebug(ReportsTrigger.class, "Reset is called");   
        done = false;
    }
}
```

**Quartz Job**

```
public class ReportsJob extends QuartzJobBean {

    private AbstractEndpoint inputEndpoint;
    private ReportsTrigger inputEndpointTrigger;    

    public void setInputEndpoint(final AbstractEndpoint pInputEndpoint) {
        this.inputEndpoint = pInputEndpoint;
    }
    public void setInputEndpointTrigger(final ReportsTrigger pInputEndpointTrigger) {
        this.inputEndpointTrigger = pInputEndpointTrigger;
    }
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(final JobExecutionContext pParamJobExecutionContext)
    throws JobExecutionException {      
        inputEndpoint.stop();
        inputEndpointTrigger.reset();
        inputEndpoint.start();
        Log.logDebug(ReportsJob.class, "Job runnnnnnning");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, be more specific and share your potential configuration. Actually `<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>` does exactly what you need: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound

Comment: Hi Artem I have updated my query. Actually I want to parse the downloaded files and insert them into database tables

Answer (score 0):

> Actually I want to parse the downloaded files and insert them into database tables

Well. Since FTP adapter polls the remote directory, stores those files to local one and sends the one by one as `Message.payload` (`File` object), there is no stops to do some custom process for each of them in the downstream flow.

E.g. you can use `<int-file:file-to-string-transformer>` and provide some further custom parser as `<transformer ref="">`.

In the end there is just enough to get deal with `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>` to store the data from `payload` to the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have to parse 6 different files (5 .txt and 1.csv) and insert into 6 different tables. So how do I use <int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter> to store each file into different table?

Comment: Well. For this porpose there is `router` component, which determines the target destination by the `Message` content. And, of course, several `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>` for each type for each target table.

Comment: My csv file contains data with column headers and values. I am facing challenges in transforming the csv files to POJOs. I am able to insert the hard coded data into DB using  <int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter  
        id="jdbcOutBoundAdapterEndpoint1" channel="sentFileChannel"  
        query="insert into Sample (COl1, COl2, COl3) values(1, 5206,1111)"  
        data-source="dataSource">  
    </int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: If you have an issue with CSV transformation, it will be a new question though. You can take a look to the Spring Batch abilities: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#simpleDelimitedFileReadingExample