# Spring Integration - Run Flow on Application Startup

Tags: spring-integration

I need to run a custom inbound channel adapter once, when the application starts up, is this possible? If yes how?

I tried looking into pollers but they accept time intervals, delays and crons. I don't think any of these are suitable for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `FireOnceTrigger` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563469/spring-integration-cron-quartz-in-cluster/11564543#11564543).

Create a bean of that type and reference it in the poller's `trigger` attribute:

```
<int:poller trigger="myFireOnceTrigger />
```