# Spring Cloud Stream + Quartz

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I am planning to use Spring cloud Stream for my project. I see that there's built-in Trigger source application starter. What I want to do is to use, quartz job scheduler as the source app. This is to allow dynamic job schedules from application. Is there a good sample to achieve this?

I found this. [spring integration + cron + quartz in cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563469/spring-integration-cron-quartz-in-cluster/11564543#11564543). This solution talks about getting reference to inbound channel adapter. I am using Annotation to define the inbound channel adapter. How do I get references to this object so that I can do start / stop mentioned in the solution.

This is how i define inbound channel adapter.

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup = "false", value = SourceChannel.CHANNEL_NAME, poller = @Poller(trigger = "fireOnceTrigger"))
public MessageSource<String> timerMessageSource() {
    return new MessageSource<String>() {
        public Message<String> receive() {
            System.out.println("******************");
            System.out.println("At the Source");
            System.out.println("******************");
            String value = "{\"value\":\"hi\"}";
            System.out.println("Sending value: " + value);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(value).setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json").build();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/138

The algorithm to build a bean name for automatically created endpoints is like:

> The bean names are generated with this algorithm: * The `MessageHandler` (`MessageSource`) `@Bean` gets its own standard name from the method name or name attribute on the `@Bean`. This works like there is no Messaging Annotation on the `@Bean` method. * The `AbstractEndpoint` bean name is generated with the pattern: `[configurationComponentName].[methodName].[decapitalizedAnnotationClassShortName]`. For example the endpoint (`SourcePollingChannelAdapter`) for the `consoleSource()` definition above gets a bean name like: `myFlowConfiguration.consoleSource.inboundChannelAdapter`.

See [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans) for more information.