# Spring Boot Quartz, Integration Inbound channel adapter and trigger bindings

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

We have  Quartz Job + File Integration adapter using XML configurations and is working fine, however since trying to move to Spring Boot and these configurations to annotations

Below is the XML configuration for which I am looking for equivalent annotations and bindings

```
<bean id="scheduler" 
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="inboundadapterendpoint"><ref bean="incomingfiles" /></entry>
                <entry key="inboundendpointtrigger"><ref bean="incomingfiles-trigger"/></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="inboundendpointtrigger" class="abc.xyz.Trigger" />

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="incomingfiles" channel="xyz" directory=""  scanner="recursiveScanner" auto-startup="false" prevent-duplicates="false">
    <integration:poller task-executor="fileChannelTaskExecutor" trigger="incomingfiles-trigger" max-messages-per-poll="1">
    </integration:poller>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

How do we get the Inbound Adapter Bean & poller trigger 
created using annotations below  is  injected during scheduler factory creation in spring Boot quartz config

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(poller = @Poller(trigger="customTrigger")
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {

}
```

Thanks  in advance for any help or suggestions regarding the same

Artem Bilan, thanks very much for the response.

Follow up question post trying out the code provided in response

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomTrigger inboundEndPointTrigger;

    @Autowired
    private AbstractEndpoint incomingFiles;


    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {

    System.out.println("incomingFiles value is  " + incomingFiles);

    }   
}



@Bean(name = "incomingFiles")
@InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup = "false", value = "xyz", poller = @Poller(trigger = "inboundEndPointTrigger", maxMessagesPerPoll = "2", errorChannel = "abc"))
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {

}
```

Output of above is reference for errorLogger instead of  Inbound Channel Adapter.

incomingFiles value is  bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'

How do i bind the exact Inbound Adapter with name incomingFiles to scheduler factory ?

---

Update after trying out with @EndPointId...

```
  @Bean
  @EndPointId("incomingFiles")
    @InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup = "false", value = "xyz", poller = @Poller(trigger = "inboundEndPointTrigger", maxMessagesPerPoll = "2", errorChannel = "abc"))
    public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {

    }

System.out.println("incomingFiles value is  " + incomingFiles);  print in  QuartzConfig class above is still giving a reference to  Logger object 

incomingFiles value is  bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
```

Found the response in below SO ([Spring Cloud Stream + Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558655/spring-cloud-stream-quartz) )  on how the bean will be created for Inbound Channel Adapter.

```
Since the AbstractEndPoint is returning the logger reference instead of InboundChannelAdapter , 
is it ok to  get the Inbound Adapter channel bean reference via application context  in scheduler factory ? are there any issues with this ?

try {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) context.getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContext");
    AbstractEndpoint abstractEndPoint = (AbstractEndpoint) applicationContext
                    .getBean("fileConfig.fileReadingMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter");
} catch(SchedulerException ex) {
}


fileConfig is the Spring File integration configuration class name where InboundChannelAdapter is defined..
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have closed your old question - you could just edit it properly and we would have a link to other question. But anyway, the answer is like this:

Any XML bean definition could be declared in Java & annotation config with a `@Bean` method definition.

So, that `<bean id="inboundendpointtrigger" class="abc.xyz.Trigger" />` would be in Java like this:

```
@Bean
Trigger customTrigger() {
   return new abc.xyz.Trigger();
}
```

You already use its bean name as a reference in the `@Poller`.

The same you do for the `SchedulerFactoryBean` and configure its `setSchedulerContextAsMap()` in that `@Bean` method. You have already a `customTrigger()` bean for reference and do get access to the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` endpoint based on the `@InboundChannelAdapter`, you need to inject into a `@Bean` method. Kinda this:

```
 @Bean
 SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory(Trigger trigger, SourcePollingChannelAdapter endpoint) {

 }
```

Don't forget to use an `@InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup = "false")` as Gary recommends in other SO question.

Comment: Thanks very much Artem.  I can have many SourcePollingChannelAdapter so which one it would pick. In my case  
Do i need to use fileReadingMessageSource since the Bean name will be the 

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(poller = @Poller(trigger="customTrigger")
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {

}

Comment: Please, stop placing multi-line code into the comments. It is much better to edit your question with the proper formatting.

Comment: Answering to you question. No, you can't use a `fileReadingMessageSource` for Quartz, because it is a `MessageSource`, but we need an `AbstractEndpoint`. That is what is created by the framework as a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. Right, you can have many of them and you definitely need to qualify it properly. For this purpose we have an `@EndpointId` annotation to pace alongside with that `@InboundChannelAdapter`. And then you use the id from there for autowiring.

Comment: wow,thanks again very much for your quick response and help. Will try it out

Comment: Bilian, Tried with EndpointId,  but there reference of end point autowired is of logger. I have made edit's to my question  with the code changes tried.  Any inputs or suggestions will be really helpful.  Again thanks in advance for any help or suggestion..