# Is there anyway to tweak Feed Adapter to act based on event?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

scenario:- lets say there is message channel which is receiving message from any flow and if that channel received any messages then feed adapter should pull feed (once) and publish those feeds to other channel. after that feed adapter should stop. are there any possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: You can use a custom trigger that only fires once. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563469/spring-integration-cron-quartz-in-cluster/11564543#11564543).

Comment: See my answer, please

Answer (score 0):

The `FeedEntryMessageSource` is based on the:

```
Reader reader = this.feedUrl != null
                    ? new XmlReader(this.feedUrl)
                    : new XmlReader(this.feedResource.getInputStream());
            SyndFeed feed = this.syndFeedInput.build(reader);
```

from the `com.rometools:rome` library. So, you can take this and build some custom service activator which is going to be activated by the message on its input channel from that event.

For better feed parsing logic understanding I suggest to take a look into `FeedEntryMessageSource` source code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-feed/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/feed/inbound/FeedEntryMessageSource.java

**UPDATE**

Well, another way is just to have a `FeedEntryMessageSource` as a bean and refer to its `receive()` method from the service activator. This way it is going to be called on demand when message arrives on the input channel of that service activator fully ignoring message content.